# Python strange behaviour with string on server

Tags: python, string

I have no idea.
If I run this locally it works perfectly fine but when I run it on my server that hasn't had a problem before it suddenly gets weird. OK.
The string should be:
"First_Second_Name+Show_Name+extra+yes"
but I'm getting:
"+extra+yesFirst_SecShow_Nd_Nam"

```
randomList = cPickle.load(open('file.pkl'), 'r')
randomSelected = random.choice(randomList)
name = randomSelected[0]
show = randomSelected[1]
print name
print show
```

Everything so far is fine it prints:

```
First Second Name
Show Name
```

But as soon as I use .replace it gets weird.

```
name = name.replace(" ", "_")
```

print name
First_Second_Name
OK fine now to put everything together

```
endURL = name + show.replace(" ", "_") + "+extra+yes"
print endURL
"+extra+yesFirst_SecShow_Nd_Nam"
```

It just doesn't add up to me. It all seems perfectly fine until I mix it with another string. Any Ideas?

Comment: In the first snippet you print `name` two times, but you say it prints two different strings, that doesn't add up to me either :P. Please make sure you provide a correct example.

Comment: randomList is something I just cut it short as it's just opening a file. @rednaw mistake on my end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are [CRs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return) at the end of some of your strings. Strip them before using the strings.

Comment: I didn't expect it to be that. It worked thank you! I was stumped on this for a bit. Will select as answer when I can.

Comment: @user1043816,  It is often helpful to see exactly what's in a string.  You can do that with repr(), e.g. print repr(name)  => 'First_Second_Name\n'.  Note that your output for name indicates there are no newlines at the end of the name line.  Did you not post the output correctly?